# Drill Down Capabilities in Reports

Tags: dashboard, drilldown, drillthrough

I am looking for a suggestions on technologies, platform, reporting tool or any other information on implementing drill down capabilities within a dashboard. Can I do it in python or google looker or Power BI? Tableau does not seem to be the solution because the reports does not perform with many action filters. I am looking for a more robust solution . My intension is to have user be able to click on  high level charts and go to data lines based on all filter condition applied till that point.

It is very similar to this  here:
https://help.lever.co/hc/en-us/articles/4403179920909-Visual-Insights-Drill-downs o